# Can I run all the instances of a deployed service in Apache Ignite?

Tags: .net, ignite

Is it possible to run all the instances of a deployed service in Apache Ignite? The service returns some per node state information based on the contents of the Ignite's SQL store on the nodes. I need to get it to execute on every node in the group, not on a random single node.

I tried to use the Broadcast() to call a function on all the applicable nodes which, in turn, calls the service. It does work but is there a more straightforward method to achieve this?

Also, I would not like to use solely the Compute grid, as this requires me to bring all the dependencies in the above logic into the calling service -- basically inject the target service's code into the caller.

I use Apache Ignite for Net v2.7. Thank you!

Comment: You could run a service on each node by setting ServiceConfiguration#setTotalCount(0) and ServiceConfiguration#setMaxPerNodeCount(1).

Comment: @PavelVinokurov Thank you. Should I set that before calling the service in the caller code? Is that API available in the .NET edition?

Comment: In the .NET edition you could call IServices#deployNodeSingleton method documented in https://ignite.apache.org/releases/latest/dotnetdoc/api/Apache.Ignite.Core.Services.IServices.html#Apache_Ignite_Core_Services_IServices_DeployNodeSingleton_System_String_Apache_Ignite_Core_Services_IService_

Comment: Yes It should be set before calling the services. Also these parameters could be set in the service configuration section - IgniteConfiguration#setServiceConfiguration

Comment: @PavelVinokurov Probably I did not articulated the question clearly. I did deploy the service (yes, I used deployNodeSingleton) and now I need to call every instance of the service across the cluster. As far I as understand, IServices#GetServiceProxy<T>() calls a random instance. Is it possible to call every deployed instance of the service across the cluster?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could specify the cluster group for IgniteServices#services(ClusterGroup).
Below the example of calling the service on each server node:

```
Collection<ClusterNode> nodes = ignite.cluster().forServers().nodes();
for (ClusterNode node : nodes) {
            ExampleService service = ignite.services(ignite.cluster().forNode(node)).service("service");
            service.call();
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I'll try